# .htaccess file does not recognize index.php

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have created a .htaccess file that allows for vanity URLs. However, I am no longer able to type www.website.com without typing in the index file. I.e. I have to type in www.website.com/index.php in order to see the homepage. This is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/profile.php?u=$1 [NC]
```

Anyone know how to fix this? Thank you all!

Comment: Is this `.htaccess` file on `www.website.com` host's document root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you defined your rule increased the complexity.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

Above rule means *if file name is a directory of file process as it is. after that dont process farther*.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/profile.php?u=$1 [NC]
```

This rule means *map any request uri to `profile.php?u=`*

Now when you request `/` that is `www.website.com` it checks the first rule and it fails to match. Then it check the second rule and maps it to `profile.php?u=`.

1. One way to fix it, would be check *if `$_GET['u']` is empty or `/` in `profile.php`. If it is then load the `index.php`.
2. Another way is to find a proper regular expression for your user names once found use it here.

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(USERNAME_REGEX)$ http://www.website.com/profile.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
   ```

The best way to handle this is using PHP,

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?uri=$1 [L]
```

Now `index.php` will get every uri you pass. Now you can process the URI in `index.php`.

Answer (score 2):

It may be due to your server set up.
Try `DirectoryIndex index.php` (see http://davidwalsh.name/directory-index-homepage-htaccess )

**Edit** (due to me not reading the question properly in the first place)

Have you tried it without the RewriteRule .* - [L] line?

Comment: If that was the case. www.website.com would not have worked before he added the .htaccess but he clearly says it no longer works.

Comment: My apologys, lack of concentration hits again. Have you tried it without the `RewriteRule .* - [L]` line?